# OpenCV on MS Visual Studio 10: cv::cvtColor causes Entry Point Not Found Error Message

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I am using **OpenCV 2.3.1 Win Superpack** on MS Visual C++ 10.0.4 on MS Windows 7.  Some OpenCV functions run file but cv::cvtColor seems to call msvcp80d.dll, msvcr80d.dll, gpsvc.dll, IEShims.dll and sysntfy.dll.  When I add them to my search path I get the following message.

> The procedure entry point
>   ?free@allocate_root_with_contect_proxy@tbb@@QBEXAAVtask@3@@Z could not
>   be located in the dynamic link library tbb_debug.dll.

Dependency Walker says that I have 64-bit versions of SYSNTFY.DLL and GPSVC.dll where I need 32-bit versions but I copied the files from the System 32(C:\windows) directory.  Maybe I need to download the 32-bit versions of those two DLLs but I have not been able to find them on the web.

Many thanks in advance,
Peter.

Answer (score 2):

The superpack is built agsinst vs2008 - if you want to use debug builds with vs2010 it's easier to just build it from source with vs2010

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to get back.  That was the problem.  I appear to have fixed it by using http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe/download instead.  Thanks.