# object matching using surf detector

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, homography, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I am trying to detect an object from an image using SURF detector. For that I have tried to debug the code provided by OpenCV:

```
OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack\opencv\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\features2D\SURF_Homography.cpp
```

but it constantly shows runtime error..

```
"The procedure entrypoint?
destroy@task_base@internal@interface5@tbb@SAXAAVtask@4@@z could not be located in the dynamic link library tbb_debug.dll"
```

can you tell  me the reason behind this?

Comment: have a look to this post, they're discussing a similar error message.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621813/opencv-on-ms-visual-studio-10-cvcvtcolor-causes-entry-point-not-found-error-m

Comment: Looks like a problem with versions, and libraries.

Comment: if its a problem with versions and libraries then it should happen for other code s also.but i only face this problem only for this particular code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am using opencv_calib3d231.lib instead of opencv_calib3d231d.lib ...and it works.Thank you